# Elevation data API for Spain

Tags: api

I would like to obtain the accumulated elevation from a request with lat and long.

I need an open data API without limit like OpenStreetMap but with elevation.

Comment: Are you familiar with https://www.usgs.gov/products/data-and-tools/gis-data? Their site is very poorly designed, but, somewhere on there, that have 9m data (perhaps better) for the whole world, including Spain.

Comment: I've never hear about it. I've seen this page, but I can't understant how I can obtain the accumulated elevation with a http request. Can you show me an example?

Comment: Sorry, see if https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/GMTED2010 is more helpful.

Comment: I was bored, so https://www.dropbox.com/s/xada9pibbzy1lzj/GMTED2010N30E000_075.zip?dl=0 and https://www.dropbox.com/s/u50yb75xh9gdiz8/GMTED2010N30W030_075.zip?dl=0 cover Spain and more. Let me know if you need help with these.

Comment: Thanks. If now I import these files and I extract the values from the raster, Can I obtain the elevation?

Comment: Yes, the raster values are the elevations. I don't know the format offhand, but it shouldn't be hard to find. Google around, but ping me if you need help. There should be detailed docs somewhere.

Comment: @BarryCarter In the Dropbox folder there are some .tif. Which are the differents between 30n030w_20101117_gmted_bln075 and 30n030w_20101117_gmted_max075? The second one could be the máximum but What is the meaning of bln?

Comment: I never noticed the "bln" and "max" difference (btw, you can get these yourself in case I got the wrong ones: https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/GMTED2010). They cover two different areas. Google hangouts me at: carter.barry@gmail.com and you can self-answer w/ whatever we come up with. Or https://topomaps.usgs.gov/drg/drg_overview.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an API to return elevation at a location have you looked at the Google Elevation API? More information can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/start).

Comment: I know that, but I need an API without limit and free.

Comment: How many queries are you going to make? You get 2,500 free requests per day! If that is not enough then it's $0.50 USD / 1000 additional requests, up to 100,000 daily. May be you should edit you question to indicate what you intentions are and the volume of data processing rather than just stating what you want? I would say 2,500 free queries per day is pretty good! It's probably cost us a few dollars of our time to just discuss this...